# Writting text to file c#.it's being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a text file and after that I am trying to write some text in that file.but when writing text,it's generating exception that process cannot access file because it's being used by another process. Kindly someone help :( Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

```
dt_Loc = loc1_ctab.GetEmpLocInfo(Session["empcd"].ToString());
string str = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy");
str = dt_Loc.Rows[0]["loc1_abrv"].ToString() + "-" + str;

string path = FilesPath.Path_SaveFile + str + ".txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
    tw.WriteLine(txt_comments.Text);
    tw.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you find out which other process/application is using the same file?

Comment: Sometimes while rebuilding. VS creates more than one threads. Try reopening VS.

Comment: Thanks, but i got the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code giving such error because, the method Create Creates or overwrites a file in the specified path. which will return A `FileStream` that provides read/write access to the file specified in path. So at the time of executing the writemethod, the file is being used by the returned FS. you can use this in the following way:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
   Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(txt_comments.Text);
   // Add some information to the file.
   fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

You can Make it simple by using [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx) which will Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

```
string path =FilesPath.Path_SaveFile + str + ".txt";;
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.WriteAllText(path, txt_comments.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the File.Create since it opens a FileStream for the file.This results in the file being open and hence you get the exception that the file is being used by another process.

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
{            
     using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
     {
         sw.WriteLine(txt_comments.Text);
     }
}
```